# Use HTML JavaScript attribute "onSOMETHING" or add a Event Listener on Script for all elements at once?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Well I use a script that get a external JSON from a file, and loop thru its objects and creates the HTML on a string then after all is done, it appends in the DOM. But I would like to know if it's better to use for example: `onclick` html attribute (directly into the code) or add an event listener to all html objects by its classes at once with JavaScript after appending to the DOM.

Is it the same speed or one is faster than the other and why?
I use a lot of HTML objects so I really need to know that, to get the best performance of it.

Comment: html attributes are the wrong choice. Always favour DOM methods. If you want attachment speed use event delegation

Comment: @Raynos—attributes aren't always the wrong choice, it depends on the case. For speed, they will beat dynamically added listeners every time. Delegation is an option, it can be done either way (as attributes or dynamically).

Comment: @RobG do you have real benchmarks proving DOM0 attributes have a non neglible speed increase over DOM2 listeners?

Comment: @Raynos—Listeners attached dynamically must wait for the element to exist before they can be added, in-line listeners don't, so logic says they are attached sooner. Waiting for a ready or load event means all elements (and their listeners, if they have any) are available before any dynamic listeners are added.

Comment: @RobG but what's the cost? Global scope for all your listeners? Besides `<element><script> bindToElement() </script>` I doubt the following makes a real difference. And of course adding delegated events to the `document` in a script in the `<head>` attaches the listeners sooner then in line DOM0 attributes.

Comment: Actually, "delegation" compares strings in the bubbled event so overall performance suffers.

Comment: @Raynos - scope is rarely an issue, use a namespace object if it might be. In-page script elements are an option, but it seems counter productive to use them to dynamically attach a listener that could have been added in-line with far less code. Whether delegation is used is irrelevant (in this case), it just reduces the number of listeners, a listener must still be attached. In-line listeners are there when the element is, any other method will attach it later (though of course it may be soon enough afterward to not matter).

Comment: @user539484—yes, with delegation performance of the actual listener suffers but in a well design system, not enough to matter. It can hugely reduce the number of listeners (e.g. click events in cells of a very large table). I was just trying to point out that there are pros and cons to each approach.

Comment: @RobG still, the hard coupling between html and javascript is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using some simple [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/):

```
// works on existing and future elements
// since we are attaching to the parent
var d = document;
d.getElementById("theParentOfAppendedElements").onclick = function (e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "something" 
        && e.target.className === "appended") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Using event delegation doesn't preclude using one method or the other. Excatly the same can be done with a single inline listener, which is much less complex, reliable and consistent across-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use unobtrusive javascript. I put all scripts in separate js files and all events are hooked up in those scripts. This way I am no longer mixing markup and script and I reduce the size of the markup. This limits the bandwidth consumption. And since javascript files are cached by client browsers, this improves the performance of the website.